# TypeScript definitions should always include compilerOptions "types": ["node"],

Tags: typescript-typings

If a `main.d.ts` definition file includes `dependency.d.ts` file which has `/// <reference types="node" />` at the top then in the main.d.ts file you can use the following without error:

```
import http = require("http");
import stream = require("stream");
import Events = require("events");
// etc...
```

This is very confusing as the module resolution is not obvious.  If `"types": ["node"],` was in the `tsconfig.json` of both `.d.ts` files it would be slightly easier to understand for beginners.  Is this the best way of specifying a where the dependencies on node definitions are to be found or is `/// <reference types="node" />` the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended not to use `"types": ["node"]` at all but to use `/// <reference types="..." />` directives in source files.

> Use `/// <reference types="..." />` directives in source files and ensure that the "types" field in your tsconfig is an empty array.

From a [DefinitelyTyped build error log](https://travis-ci.org/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/builds/229720940?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification).